# Android Fragment Implementation

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to implement Fragments in my Project using the https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator plugin.

My Fragment

```
public final class NearByFragment extends Fragment {
    private static String TAG = "bMobile";

    public static NearByFragment newInstance(String content) {
        NearByFragment fragment = new NearByFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView");
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_nearby, null);
    }
}
```

Now I want to execute some code like start start a new thread and download a JSON from the server and then assign a list view from the content I download. In fragments we are assigning views in onCreateView. so where should I write the

```
listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_items);

((TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_text))
                .setText(R.string.description_blocked);
```

and other code to generate the Fragment view ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search within the view that you just inflated:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView");
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_nearby, null);
        listview = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_items);
        ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.title_text))
                        .setText(R.string.description_blocked);
        return v;
    }
```

You can also use the [Fragment.getView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getView%28%29) function elsewhere in your code and call that view's `findViewById()` member.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getActivity().findByView()` from the Fragment if you want to have access to the layout elements. Alternatively, you can just put the `findByView()` call in the main Activity.